# VBScript, Open IE, sometimes visible=true brings it foreground, sometimes not

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, visible, foreground

I am trying to open an Internet Explorer using

```
Set ie = createobject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "www.google.com"
ie. Application.visible = true
```

Strangely, on some devices the new IE window will open in foreground(most front, become the active window) whereas others open in semi-foreground(usually second one, turns active when minimizes current active window).

Wondering if anyone knows what causes the differences?
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Help for SetForegroundWindow in Windows API.

> Remarks
>
> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A
> process can set the foreground window only if one of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> •The process is the foreground process.
>
> •The process was started by the foreground process.
>
> •The process received the last input event.
>
> •There is no foreground process.
>
> •The process is being debugged.
>
> •The foreground process is not a Modern Application or the Start Screen.
>
> •The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
>
> •The foreground lock time-out has expired (see
> SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
>
> •No menus are active.
>
> An application cannot force a window to the foreground while the user
> is working with another window. Instead, Windows flashes the taskbar
> button of the window to notify the user

So what this means, if a foreground program starts a program the new program has two seconds to create or activate a window or can lose that right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
Does this mean, in my case, the IE window failed to be create/activated in two seconds?
I have discovered that my devices has different  ForegroundLockTimeout values. Once I modified it into 0, the new IE window I create will become activated. Wondering what modifies it from the default 200000 automatically...

Comment: I can't say. Note it only loses the right in 2 secs if the user does something (or a program does something that makes windows think a user may have done it).

Answer (score 0):

IE window will not open in foreground if any other windows is maximized. You can try to fix that, by selecting icons to never combine on the taskbar.

To ensure activation of window on any device, you can use AppActivate:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
objie.navigate "www.google.com"
objIE.Visible = 1
objShell.AppActivate objIE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. On those devices, even at desktop screen, the IE window is still inactive. I did researched about the AppActivate solution, just curious about what causes the different result of different devices.
Thanks again for your answer.